# About "synchronus operations" in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

some text from a android book:

> "However, starting with Android 3.0,  synchronous operations can no
>   longer be run directly from a UI  thread. "

I think that every code running in the some thread is "synchronous operations "
so,What is the "synchronous operations" mean ?

How the android runtime detect that the code is a  "synchronous operations "

Comment: probably incorrect phrasing, and means that long-running operations cannot be run in the UI thread without android complaining.

Comment: Also, doing any sort of Network operations on the UI Thread will cause an exception to be thrown.

Comment: I would imagine that the phrase "synchronous operations" is in the context of whatever topic you are reading about. That being said, nothing specifically changed in Android 3.0 related to work on the main application thread (a.k.a., UI thread). Perhaps you need [a different book](http://commonsware.com/Android)... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Alex Lockwood](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html) writes:

> The reason why your application crashes on Android versions 3.0 and above, but works fine on Android 2.x is because Honeycomb and Ice Cream Sandwich are much stricter about abuse against the UI Thread.

citing the following quote from the [Android Developer site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html):

> A NetworkOnMainThreadException is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread. This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

That means big processing operations can't run synchronously with the main thread (UI).

That is a problem that didn't exist in old versions of Android (like 2.2), so, when a long-running process started, the user couldn't do anything unless the process ended.

Btw, i agree they didn't choose the best words in the world.